# Android - strange errors in logcat not allowing app to run

Tags: android

I'm having trouble understanding what the problem is here. My android app doesn't run at all, here's the logcat output.

```
09-26 20:21:35.609    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-26 20:21:35.609    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
09-26 20:21:35.646    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
09-26 20:21:35.749    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.savag.myapplication-2/lib/x86
09-26 20:21:36.804    2540-2551/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5990(393KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 10MB/10MB, paused 17.760ms total 60.005ms
09-26 20:21:36.886    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-26 20:21:36.886    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-26 20:21:36.906    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17(848B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 17MB/21MB, paused 2.261ms total 18.538ms
09-26 20:21:36.910    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-26 20:21:36.965    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18(784B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 17MB/21MB, paused 2.299ms total 54.124ms
09-26 20:21:36.967    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-26 20:21:36.988    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 17MB/21MB, paused 2.902ms total 19.329ms
09-26 20:21:36.989    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 66MB allocation
09-26 20:21:36.991    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-26 20:21:37.011    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 17MB/21MB, paused 2.322ms total 19.763ms
09-26 20:21:37.013    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication W/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 70056012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 46MB until OOM"
09-26 20:21:37.014    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-26 20:21:37.015    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-26 20:21:37.032    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(560B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 17MB/21MB, paused 2.341ms total 15.687ms
09-26 20:21:37.034    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-26 20:21:37.051    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 17MB/21MB, paused 2.313ms total 16.234ms
09-26 20:21:37.053    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-26 20:21:37.171    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 17MB/21MB, paused 26.229ms total 116.717ms
09-26 20:21:37.182    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 66MB allocation
09-26 20:21:37.183    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-26 20:21:37.202    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 17MB/21MB, paused 2.250ms total 17.745ms
09-26 20:21:37.205    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication W/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 70056012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 46MB until OOM"
09-26 20:21:37.206    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication D/skia﹕ --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
09-26 20:21:37.207    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-26 20:21:37.207    2540-2540/com.example.savag.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.savag.myapplication, PID: 2540
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.savag.myapplication/com.example.savag.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.savag.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.savag.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.savag.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 70056012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 46MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.savag.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

One of the errors I think I know, and that's to do with memory, to be honest I don't have all that much on screen, (in my opinion anyway) I assume I need to do some sort of aysnc to overcome that? The others fly past me without raising an idea.
Some clarification would be appreciated please.

XML layout added for clarification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tugsedit"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/topbarmaincenter"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="245dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logoandbar4"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/motionbuttonup"
            android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/positionbuttonup"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:clickable="false" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/envirobuttonup"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And for the .Java:

```
package com.example.savag.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show layout at line 34(+-10).

Comment: Not allowed to add pictures I think?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 70056012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 46MB until OOM

Comment: Yeah I got that part, unsure how to fix that either. But it's alllll the other stuff that's a problem

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if something may be wrong with you layout inflators.

Comment: THank you for the quick reply. Expand please.

Comment: I believe that your XML file is failing to load. You can see that because it is saying the error is on line 13 of MainActivity, and line 13 is what starts up the set content view file. Try adding android:tools to your linear layout, and set the tools to your main activity file. I am not positive that that will work, but try it and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You have to show your xml files to 100% get solution. This is most times happens when you loading TOO big image to your screen. Try not to load data at all and likely this problem disappear.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. XML added.

Comment: Yeah, your xml seems not laggy. Try to use colors as your `background` and images `src` and problem might disappear. The images could be too big.

Comment: Too big, you mean size in bytes or in physical size?

Comment: Second that, start by removing src / background drawables from your layout components

Comment: I genuinely need them though, surely it can't be that I can't have background image drawables heh

Answer (score 1):

I think, your android app background image is to large. Please go to the AndroidManifest.xml and add this line code in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```